How to expand or collapse all accordions in an ion-accordion-group at once?
I would expect something like this to work:
<button (click)="myAccordionGroup.expandAll()">Expand all</button>
<ion-accordion-group #myAccordionGroup>
  <ion-accordion>
    <ion-item slot="header">
      <ion-label>First Accordion</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <div slot="content">First accordion content</div>
  </ion-accordion>
  <ion-accordion>
    <ion-item slot="header">
      <ion-label>Second Accordion</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <div slot="content">Second accordion content</div>
  </ion-accordion>
</ion-accordion-group>

But IonAccordionGroup.expandAll does not exist as a method. In fact, IonAccordionGroup does not expose any methods at the time of this writing.
As a workaround, I managed to do it by manually assigning values to each ion-accordion and then set the value of the ion-accordion-group to an array containing all of those values. To collapse all accordions at once, I set the value of ion-accordion-group to an empty array.
But I'm looking for a way that:

does not force me to manually assign values to each of the ion-accordion elements.
does not force me to manage the ion-accordion-group state in my component.


At the time of this writing, IonAccordionGroup does not provide a method that lets you do it in the way that you described.
Your "workaround" is the correct way to do it.
You can create a custom Angular directive to reduce complexity:
import { ContentChildren, Directive, QueryList } from "@angular/core";
import { IonAccordion, IonAccordionGroup } from "@ionic/angular/standalone";

@Directive({
  selector: "[appAccordionGroupToggle]",
  exportAs: "appAccordionGroupToggle",
  standalone: true,
})
export class AccordionGroupToggleDirective {
  // get a reference to the ion-accordion instances inside
  @ContentChildren(IonAccordion) accordions!: QueryList<IonAccordion>;

  // get a reference to the ion-accordion-group instance
  constructor(private host: IonAccordionGroup) {}

  expand() {
    // setting the value of the ion-accordion-group to an array of all the 
    // ion-accordion values will expand all ion-accordions
    this.host.value = this.accordions.map((accordion) => accordion.value);
  }

  collapse() {
    // setting the value of the ion-accordion-group to an empty array will 
    // collapse all ion-accordions inside
    this.host.value = [];
  }
}

In your component, you can use it like this:
@Component({
  ...
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    ...
    AccordionGroupToggleDirective,
  ],
})
export class MyComponent {
}

<button (click)="toggler.expand()">Expand all</button>
<button (click)="toggler.collapse()">Collapse all</button>

<ion-accordion-group appAccordionGroupToggle
    #toggler="appAccordionGroupToggle">
  <ion-accordion>
    <ion-item slot="header">
      <ion-label>First Accordion</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <div slot="content">First accordion content</div>
  </ion-accordion>
  <ion-accordion>
    <ion-item slot="header">
      <ion-label>Second Accordion</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <div slot="content">Second accordion content</div>
  </ion-accordion>
</ion-accordion-group>

